# Asp.net identity get facebook information

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, owin

I have searched online on the following code for getting code information, but I have some questions

1) `facebook.Options.Scope.Add("email")` : How to determine what to put in email? For example what should I put if I need name or first name?

2) `ext.Claims.First(x => x.Type.Contains("email")).Value;`
How do I determine the email here? Let's say I want first name, how do I know the first name is first_name of first-name of firstname

```
 var facebookOptions = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AppId = "AppId",
                AppSecret = "AppSecret"
            };
            facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");
            app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);

 ClaimsIdentity ext = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            var email = ext.Claims.First(x => x.Type.Contains("email")).Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly get all of Facebook profile information from claims added through facebookOptions scope. You have to add scopes like below and use FacebookClient as explain.

```
var facebookOptions = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AppId = "AppId",
                AppSecret = "AppSecret"
            };
            facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");            
            facebookOptions.Scope.Add("public_profile");
            app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
```

Then you can get Facebook user information using FacebookClient.

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<ActionResult> FacebookInfo()
{
    var claimsforUser = await UserManager.GetClaimsAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    var access_token = claimsforUser.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "FacebookAccessToken").Value;
    var fb = new FacebookClient(access_token);
    dynamic myInfo = fb.Get("/me"); **// Check this with Facebook api to get profile information.**

}
```

**Note that:** If you only need to get Facebook user full name, then check your claims, you'll see user's full name is there.

[More information](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/get-more-information-from-social-providers-used-in-the-vs-2013-project-templates.aspx)

Hope this helps,